# How to fix ''Property [id] does not exist in this statement"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to select from 2 table a data to all users and merge this data to object that I want to return 
example 
    {
    user:{
    id:1,
    name:bla,
    saved cards:[
         {id:1, name:test},
         {id:2, name:test2}
    ]
    },
    {id:2, name:bla1, 
    saved cards:[ 
     {id:1, name:test},
     {id:2, name:test2},
     {id:3, name:test3}
    ]
    }
    }

```
 public function getalluser(Request $request)
    {
        $User_data = User::where('users.role', '=', 0)
            ->get();

        $count = count($User_data);
       for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $json_data[] = [
                'user' => User::where('users.role', '=', 0)
                    ->where( 'users.id', $User_data->id[$i])
                    ->leftJoin('webrole', 'users.role', '=', 'webrole.id')
                    ->get(),
                'saved cards' => User::where('users.role', '=', 0)
                    ->where( 'credit_cards.user_id', $User_data->id[$i])
                    ->leftJoin('credit_cards', 'users.id', '=', 'credit_cards.user_id')
                    ->get()
            ];

        } 
        return response()->json($User_data);
    }
```

Comment: try to use foreach instead of forloop

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($User_data as $data) {
        $json_data[] = [
            'user' => User::where('users.role', '=', 0)
                ->where( 'users.id', $data->id)
                ->leftJoin('webrole', 'users.role', '=', 'webrole.id')
                ->get(),
            'saved cards' => User::where('users.role', '=', 0)
                ->where( 'credit_cards.user_id', $data->id)
                ->leftJoin('credit_cards', 'users.id', '=', 'credit_cards.user_id')
                ->get()
        ];

    }
```